# ASP.NET MVC TASK MANAGER one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, one-to-many, relationship

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC so I have started to build small application - TASK MANAGER based on tutorials on internet (MVC Music Store, Nerd Dinner, etc ...). Ive got stuck while trying define ActionResult Method in my Controller.

I have model, where I am defining Activities. Each Activity can have several Tasks.

Activity 1  (each Activiy has got several Tasks (Task 1, Task 2, etc))
Activity 2
Activity 3
Activity n

QUESTION:

I would like to ask you for help with definition of ActionResult Method, which would return view with list of all Tasks related to selected Activity.

Picture here: http://sdrv.ms/Z46NZE

The problém is, that I am not able to define this Method as a one-to-many relationship.

Whole project here in my skydrive folder: http://sdrv.ms/ZiCbQi

Please help.

In my model, I have following classes and Context class generated by Mvcscaffolding:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace TASK3.Models
{
public class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string PN { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string ToDo { get; set; }
    public string ResponsiblePerson { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public int? TaskPriority { get; set; }
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }
    public int? ActivityPriority { get; set; }
    public string ActivityStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

}
```

Thank you very much!

Best Regards

Jaroslav Plavec

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

Remember that everything has to be serializable, ICollection is not, List is.